# Пул подключения к БД в Glassfish

Tags: glassfish

При попытке создать пул в JDBC получаю

`500 Internal Server Error и java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`

и так при любых параметрах, версия последняя под Windows

В чем может быть причина и как исправить?

Comment: Похоже что-то нехорошее делаете с выходным потоком. Одновременная запись в поток разными методами например. Попадаются аналогичные проблемы при попытке использовать поток в страницах JSP. И JSP пишет в поток по-своему и одновременно программист пытается писать по-своему.

Comment: как это понимать, если это происходит в админке сервера без единого задеплоиного приложения?

Comment: Ну это известный уже глюк. Права кто этот glassfish теперь исправлять будет? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048435/glassfish-admin-console-throws-java-lang-illegalstateexception-when-creating-jdb

Comment: все же не ясно по какой причине это происходить, в одних работает нормально, версии последние

Comment: Однако, если пройти по ссылке до баг-репортов, то можно заметить Resolution: Unresolved, и когда будет resolved даже не планируется. Пишите ручками в domain.xml

Comment: ок, спасибо, прописал вручную

Comment: Если вдруг не в курсе. Коммерческого GF больше нет и вместе с этим халявную версию тоже особо некому поддерживать. Многие перешли на другие сервера. Любители GF сделали другой халявный прожект на его основе - Payara. И вроде как развивается. Payara is supported GlassFish

Comment: спасибо за информацию, надеюсь, там не возникнет таких ошибок